# Counter cache not working in rails when creating a new value from worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, counter-cache

I have a rails app where I would like to use counter cache and before implementing into the app I tried in a sample app to check how it works and it worked so good. But I cannot make it work in the app that I were required to do.

The difference in two apps is the create being called from the controller in the app that works with counter_cache whereas the create is called from the worker on the app that does not work.

So do we need to create the record only from the controller to get it working or will it be some other error?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Code Samples**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

In my comments controller I have

```
@comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
```

and in my views I have

```
post.comments_count
```

the above code works whereas

```
Comment.create(comment_params)
```

in sidekiq worker which is called as async does not work i.e does not increment the count in table.

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code sample.

Comment: Sorry guys it works from worker too... I have made a mistake and correcting it worked. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: you can delete this Question, or post an Answer below and accept it as correct.